# how to programmatically mine tweeter sql dumps.

Tags: java, data-mining, tweets

I have a tweeter mysql dump. 
I want to build a classifier on this dump.
I want to know whether there are packages available which i can use and what type of classifier i should use. 
I want to build this classifier using java.

Comment: What is tweeter? What do you mean by "type of classifier to use"?

Comment: tweets that we get from tweeter site. I need to mine those. we get them in sql dump. I was planning to use naive-bayes classifier. As mostly it will be based on text analysis. ( but in case any different suggestion ). And lastly which package to use. I tried weka but got lost in the vastness and also not much documentation given. Any other such datamining library available?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use WEKA: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ -- WEKA contains a large number of data mining algorithms and utilities.

It has a GUI where you can experiment with various configurations and combinations of classifiers and filters on your data, and when you have built a good model, you can either embed WEKA in your java program (it is also java), and use it with a pre-built model to predict class, or use it to continuously refine the model. Or after using WEKA to experiment, you can implement the resulting decision tree or whatever in your own application so you don't have to include WEKA.

You probably want to use the 'bag-of-words' representation of the tweets, and use a classifier such as multilayer-perceptron, naive-bayes or J48 -- all available to experiment with in WEKA.

Check out this page: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA -- it has an example of text categorization at the bottom of the page.

Cheers,

Comment: any documentation you have used for this. Existing documentation is not enough. Thanx

Comment: I've edited the above with a link to an example of text categorization, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://mloss.org/software/downloads/
This link have some packages. (related to Machine Learning ) 
This is for some one who might be interested in doing the same. 
Hence answering my own question. 
Enjoy.

Comment: this will also be helpful. Though they do not adress the question directly but still they will serve as pointers http://mikebasilyan.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/weka-mysql-on-ubuntu/